# Run two dotnet processes in parallel C# with Console app .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a project with three consoles. One console will open in parallel other two processes to do some jobs (independently).

All consoles are using dotnet core framework.

`MultipleConsoleWindows` is main application which looks like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t1 = new Task(async () => { await ProcessManager.StartAsync("c1"); });
    Task t2 = new Task(async () => { await ProcessManager.StartAsync("c2"); });

    // what should do here ?

    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.Read();
}
```

and ProcessManager class:

```
public static class ProcessManager
{
    const string C1 = @"pathTo\ConsoleNumberOne.dll";
    const string C2 = @"pathTo\ConsoleNumberTwo.dll";

    public static async Task<string> StartAsync(string type)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start {type}");

        var proc = type.Equals("c1") ? C1 : C2;
        return await Task.Run(() => StartProcess(proc));
    }

    static string StartProcess(string proc)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        procStartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
        procStartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{proc}\"";
        procStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(proc);

        procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        int output = 0;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (Process pr = new Process())
        {
            pr.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

            pr.OutputDataReceived += (s, ev) =>
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ev.Data))
                {
                    return;
                }

                sb.AppendLine(ev.Data);

                string[] split = ev.Data.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                int.TryParse(split[split.Length - 1], out output);
            };

            pr.ErrorDataReceived += (s, err) =>
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(err.Data))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(err.Data);

                    output = 0;
                }
            };

            pr.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            pr.Start();
            pr.BeginOutputReadLine();
            pr.BeginErrorReadLine();

            pr.WaitForExit();

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The `ConsoleNumberOne` and `ConsoleNumberTwo` look similar

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

and

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
     Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

I'm trying to open two consoles in same time which do own job.

How to achieve that in `MultipleConsoleWindows` side ?

Comment: Why use tasks at all when you are starting separate processes? *Don't* use `WaitForExit()` if you don't want to block. If you don't block, you won't need `Task.Run` and `StartAsync`. Seems like the *real* question is how to wait for multiple child processes to exit instead before terminating

Comment: As the documentation for [WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7.2) explains, `To avoid blocking the current thread, use the Exited event.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos indeed, how to solve it? Let’s assume that I will remove waitforexit method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use `Task.Run` to start a child process. Instead of using `WaitForExit();` to block until the process exits, the [documentation suggests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7.2) :

> To avoid blocking the current thread, use the [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netframework-4.7.2) event.

Before tasks, events were one of the methods of executing jobs asynchronously and receiving notifications. This is called the `Event-Based Asynchronous Pattern`. Events can be converted to Tasks using a TaskCompletionSource. This is described in [How to: Wrap EAP Patterns in a Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-wrap-eap-patterns-in-a-task).

The example is a bit more verbose than it should. In this case, convertint `Exited` to a Task is straightforward :

```
static Task<string> StartProcess(string proc)
{

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Process pr = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = procStartInfo
        };

        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

        pr.Exited += (o, e) =>
        {
            tcs.SetResult(sb.ToString());
            pr.Dispose();
        };

        ....

        return tcs.Task;
}
```

Multiple processes can be started and awaited this way :

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var p1 = StartProcess("--version");
    var p2 = StartProcess("--list-runtimes");

    string[] responses=await Task.WhenAll(p1, p2);

    ...
}
```

[TaskCompletionSource.SetResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.setresult?view=netframework-4.7.2) completes the task returned by the tcs and sets its result, in this case a string. [SetException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1.setexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) can be used to set the task to the faulted state, raising an exception when awaited. This could be used for example to cancel awaiting if any of the processes returned a non-zero exit code

Comment: So don't need to add `BeginOutputReadLine` anymore or will be same ?

Comment: @SnakeEyes I only posted enough code to show how to handle the `Exited` event. You need `BeginOutputReadLine` to receive the `OutputDataReceived` event.

Comment: @SnakeEyes On the other hand, you don't *have* to use that event. [StandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardOutput) is a StreamReader with its own [ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [ReadLineAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readlineasync?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods. Most people would use the StreamReader instead of the event.

Comment: Thanks for explanation

Comment: @SnakeEyes the events were added way back in .NET 1.0 to allow easy programming for Windows Forms applications. You can add a `Process` class on a form as if it were another component and handle its events

Answer (score 0):

Maebe this can do the trick

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action t1 = new Action(async () => { await ProcessManager.StartAsync("c1"); });
    Action t2 = new Action(async () => { await ProcessManager.StartAsync("c2"); });
    Parallel.Invoke(t1, t2);

    Console.WriteLine("done");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: That method already returns a running task. It doesn't need `Parallel.Invoke`