# Is it possible for more than one task in Task Scheduler to run a console application (.exe file) at the same time?

Tags: c#, console-application

Let's say that there is a c# console application (.exe file) that does multiple things.  There are 2 tasks in Task Scheduler that use the console app.  Can both tasks be running at the same time (using the same console app) or do I need to schedule the tasks to not overlap?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run two dotnet processes in parallel C# with Console app .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316087/run-two-dotnet-processes-in-parallel-c-sharp-with-console-app-net-core)

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple [`Task Scheduler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page) tasks run the same console application at the same time; it will just create two instances of the same program. You should try it and find out, though, rather than asking - it's not hard to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to run multiple concurrent instances of an application from Windows Task Scheduler (just as it is possible to do manually) unless of course, you have configured the task to not start a new instance if it's already running (this can be done via the settings for the task).

What you should be careful of, however, is that your application doesn't use or lock the same resources (e.g. reading/writing files) when multiple instances are running, otherwise conflicts may occur that may cause your program to run incorrectly and/or corrupt data.